# Access Violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD

Tags: c++, stack

I am trying to make a small linked list using one structure "students" and another sturcture "stack", which holds the student structure and the pointer to the next element.

However i constantly keep getting a memmory access error. I double checked to make sure all pointers are initialized (only one pointer, Stacktop, initialized to NULL)

Here are the structure definitions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct students
{
   int matnr;
   string name;
};

struct stack
{
   students stud;
   stack *next;
};

typedef struct stack Stack;
typedef Stack *ptrStack;

void push(students s);
students pop();
int isEmpty();
void printStack(students stud);
```

Here is the push function (which keeps crashing the programm)

```
#include "stack.h"

ptrStack Stacktop = NULL;

void push(students s)
{
    ptrStack stack = (ptrStack)malloc(sizeof(Stack));

    if (stack == NULL)
    {
        cout << "!!FIN!!" << endl;
        return;
    }

    stack->stud = s;
    stack->next = Stacktop;
    Stacktop = stack;

    return; 
}
```

And here is the main:

```
#include "stack.h"

students readStuds()
{
    students s;

    cout << "Enter Student name: " << endl;
    cin >> s.name;
    cout << "Enter Matr Nr: " << endl;
    cin >> s.matnr;

    return s;
}

int main()
{

char c;

do {
        push(readStuds());

        cout << "Continue Entering Students? " << endl;
        cin >> c;
        cout << "----------------------" << endl;
        cout << "----------------------" << endl;
} while (c != 'q');

cout << " POPPING STACK " << endl;
cout << " ............. " << endl;

while (isEmpty())
{
    printStack(pop());
}
```

}

Comment: Don't use malloc in C++ (unless you *absolutely* know what youre doing)

Comment: You're using an allocated memory via malloc or new but never written by the application [When and why will an OS initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Comment: The C language does not contain `cin` or `cout`, so your C tag is not appropriate. They are *not* the same language, even though they have similarities. Please use only the tags that are actually relevant to the question you're asking; doing otherwise defeats the purpose of the tag system. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
ptrStack stack = (ptrStack)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
```

allocates enough memory to hold a `struct stack` a.k.a `Stack`, but `malloc()` does not do anything to initialize the memory that is returned. So, in particular, the `string` inside your new `stack` contains random garbage, which will then be interpreted by your `cin >> s.name`, and assumed to be a valid `string`, which it isn't, so the code fails.

Solution - use `ptrStack stack = new Stack` instead. Even better, write proper constructors/destructors, copy constructors, assignment operators, etc...

Comment: tyvm ^^ I admit i mixed a little too much C and C++, thanks to your help i just solved a problem in 2 minutes that ive been working on for 2 hours !! I completely forgot about string needing its own constructor that MUST be called during creation phase.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're mixing C and C++, specifically in this line of code

```
ptrStack stack = (ptrStack)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
```

The `Stack` structure contains an object of type `string`. The `string` constructor *must* be called before you can use the `string`. If you allocate memory using the C++ `new` operator, then the constructor is automatically called, and the `string` is properly initialized.

But if you allocate memory using the C `malloc` function, then the `string` constructor is ***not*** called. The `0xCDCDCDCD` comes from an uninitialized pointer in the string object that should have been initialized by the constructor (but wasn't because the constructor was not called).

The moral of the story: don't mix C and C++ until you have a lot of experience in both.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much ^^ that explains the uninitialized pointer problem :) 

Yea, alot of people say C/C++ are the same, but there are some drastic differences

Answer (score 1):

You're doing:

```
ptrStack stack = (ptrStack)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
                                         ^^^^^
```

which is defined as:

```
typedef Stack *ptrStack;
```

therefore, `sizeof(Stack)` is essentially `size(pointer)`. You're not allocating enough memory for your structure, you're allocating enough memory for a POINTER to your struct. So yes, you are running off the end of your allocated memory

Comment: That line 'typedefs' `ptrStack`. Isn't `Stack` defined above as `struct stack` which is defined correctly?

Comment: That's why `new` is so much safer than `malloc`: you can't get the amount of memory wrong because it's automatically calculated. It looks nicer, too.

Comment: or just `sizeof(stack)`. C/C++ are case sensitive. `stack != Stack`.